# Is there any benefit to implementing IDisposable on classes which do not have resources?

Tags: c#, idisposable

In C#, if a class, such as a manager class, does not have resources, is there any benefit to having it `: IDisposable`?

Simple example:

```
public interface IBoxManager
{
 int addBox(Box b);
}

public class BoxManager : IBoxManager
{
 public int addBox(Box b)
 {
  using(dataContext db = new dataContext()){
   db.Boxes.add(b);
   db.SaveChanges();
  }
  return b.id;
 }
}
```

Will there be any benefit in memory use when using BoxManager if it also implements IDisposable? `public class BoxManager : IBoxManager , IDisposable`

For example:

```
BoxManager bm = new BoxManager();
bm.add(myBox);
bm.dispose();//is there benefit to doing this?
```

Comment: That depends on how will you implement `Dispose()`.

Comment: I use Dispose() to un-sub from events when I no longer need the object.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There are only 2 reasons for implementing `IDisposable` on a type

- The type contains native resources which must be freed when the type is no longer used
- The type contains fields of type `IDisposable`

If neither of these are true then don't implement `IDisposable`

**EDIT**

Several people have mentioned that `IDisposable` is a nice way to implement begin / end or bookended operations.  While that's not the original intent of `IDisposable` it does provide for a very nice pattern.

```
class Operation {
  class Helper : IDisposable {
    internal Operation Operation;
    public void Dispose() {
      Operation.EndOperation();
    }
  }
  public IDisposable BeginOperation() {
    ...
    return new Helper() { Operation = this };
  }
  private void EndOperation() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Note: Another interesting way to implement this pattern is with lambdas.  Instead of giving an `IDisposable` back to the user and hoping they don't forget to call `Dispose` have them give you a lambda in which they can execute the operation and you close out the operation

```
public void BeginOperation(Action action) {
  BeginOperationCore();
  try {
    action();
  } finally {
    EndOperation();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that puts things too strongly.  Sometimes you have a "begin/end" paradigm that is perfectly captured by the `using` construct.  Stack exchange's own MiniProfiler uses this pattern, for example, to denote "chunks" of code with no basis in resource management.  The MVC framework does similar with HTML elements (specifically `<form>`).

Comment: Well, actually there's a third case: syntactic sugar. Example: ASP.NET MVC `Html.BeginForm` helper returns `IDisposable` and all that it does in the Dispose method is to render the closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: @KirkWoll, Darin agreed. I'll add that use case up there

Comment: I hate that I can't respond to both of you in the same comment.  Very annoying.

Comment: There is fourth, (and very important) use case. "Unsubscribing from Event Handlers" - This would lead to memory leaks, and it is BEST to do it explicitly in Dispose.

Comment: What about types that don't contain such fields, but their descendants might? You may find that the users of an API that returns such objects do not ever think to check `returnedValue is IDisposable`; they just see that `using (returnedValue)` is illegal and decide that no disposal is required.

Answer (score 8):

While your code wouldn't benefit from implementing IDisposable, I can't agree with other opinions here that state that IDisposable is only meant to (directly or indirectly) free native resources. IDisposable can be used whenever the object needs to perform clean up task at the end of it's lifetime span. It's extremely useful together with `using`.

A very popular example: in ASP.NET MVC `Html.BeginForm` returns an IDisposable. On creation, the object opens the  tag, when Dispose is called it closes it. No native resources involved, yet still a good use of IDisposable.

Comment: +1: Additionally, the observed object - in the IObserver/IObservable pattern - returns an IDisposable when the observer registers with the observed.

Answer (score 7):

There won't be a scrap of difference between the disposable and non-disposable version if you don't explicitly make use of the `Dispose()` method.

Comment: Great answer. It doesn't really matter what you use it for, as long as (a) you do something useful in the Dispose() method, and (b) the using(){} syntax makes sense in its context (either on the class or on a class that uses it).

Answer (score 5):

No, there will be no benefit if you don't do something useful like releasing unmanaged resources that your class might hold in the `Dispose` method.

Answer (score 4):

No, if there are no (managed or unmanaged) resources there is no need for `IDisposable` either.

Small caveat: some people use IDisposable to clean up eventhandlers or large memory buffers but

- you don't seem to use those
- it's a questionable pattern anyway.

Comment: Event handlers in many cases need to be cleaned up, or they will leak.  Classes which require cleanup should perform such cleanup when `IDisposable.Dispose` is called, if they haven't done so before then, except in cases where cleanup would be impractical without information which would be unavailable to a `Dispose` method.  Why, then, would `IDisposable.Dispose` not be an entirely proper way to clean up event handlers?

Comment: @supercat - we've been through this before. It's a rats nest you shouldn't set up in the first place.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: could you elaborate the "rats nest" comment a bit more when you get a chance? Does this mean that a class should never attach its event handlers privately, but instead delegate this to another controller-like object?

Comment: @Groo - yes , more or less. It's safe and customary to subscribe when the subscribers lifespan <= publisher lifespan. Like a Form subscribing to a button click. But for binding a Control to a DataSource an intermediate is used (that can be cleaned out quickly).

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Certainly there can be advantages to adding intermediate objects in the event chain, but who's going to tell those intermediate objects to unsubscribe, if the object that created them doesn't do so in its `Dispose` method?

Answer (score 4):

One major point of confusion, which may not be applicable in your case but arises often, is what exactly constitutes a "resource".  From the perspective of an object, an unmanaged resource is something which an outside entity (*) is "doing"(**) on its behalf, which that outside entity will keep doing--to the detriment of other entitites--until told to stop.  For example, if an object opens a file, the machine which hosts the file may grant that object exclusive access, denying everyone else in the universe a chance to use it unless or until it gets notified that the exclusive access isn't needed anymore.

(*) which could be anything, anywhere; possibly not even on the same computer.

(**) or some way in which the the behavior or state of an outside entity is altered

If an outside entity is doing something on behalf of an object which is abandoned and disappears without first letting the entity know its services are no longer required, the outside entity will have no way of knowing that it should stop acting on behalf of the object which no longer exists.  IDisposable provides one way of avoiding this problem by providing a standard means of notifying  objects when their services are not required.  An object whose services are no longer required will generally not need to ask any further favors from any other entities, and will thus be able to request that any entities that had been acting on its behalf should stop doing so.

To allow for the case where an object gets abandoned without `IDisposable.Dispose()` having been called first, the system allows objects to register a "failsafe" cleanup method called `Finalize()`.  Because for whatever reason, the creators of C# don't like the term `Finalize()`, the language requires the use of a construct called a "destructor" which does much the same thing.  Note that in general, `Finalize()` will mask rather than solve problems, and can create problems of its own, so it should be used with extreme caution if at all.

A "managed resource" is typically a name given to an object which implements `IDisposable` and usually, though not always, implements a finalizer.

Answer (score 3):

From my personal experience (confirmed with discussion and other posts here) I would say, that there could be a situations where your object use massive amount of events, or not massive amount but frequent subscriptions and unsubscription from the event which sometimes leads to that the object is not garbage collected. In this case *I* in `Dispose` unsubscribe from all events my object subscribed before.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

`IDisposable` is also great if you want to benefit the `using () {}` syntax.

In a WPF project with ViewModels, I wanted to be able to temporarily disable `NotifyPropertyChange` events from raising. To be sure other developers will re-enable notifications, I wrote a bit of code to be able to write something like:

```
using (this.PreventNotifyPropertyChanges()) {
    // in this block NotifyPropertyChanged won't be called when changing a property value
}
```

The syntax looks okay and is easily readable. For it to work, there's a bit of code to write. You will need a simple Disposable object and counter.

```
public class MyViewModel {
    private volatile int notifyPropertylocks = 0; // number of locks

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        if (this.notifyPropertylocks == 0) { // check the counter
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(...);
        }
    }

    protected IDisposable PreventNotifyPropertyChanges() {
        return new PropertyChangeLock(this);
    }

    public class PropertyChangeLock : IDisposable {
        MyViewModel vm;

        // creating this object will increment the lock counter
        public PropertyChangeLock(MyViewModel vm) {
            this.vm = vm;
            this.vm.notifyPropertylocks += 1;
        }

        // disposing this object will decrement the lock counter
        public void Dispose() {
            if (this.vm != null) {
                this.vm.notifyPropertylocks -= 1;
                this.vm = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are no resources to dispose here. I wanted a clean code with a kind of try/finally syntax. The using keyword looks better.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any benefit to having it : IDisposable?

It doesn't look so in your specific example, **however**: there is one good reason to implement `IDisposable` even if you don’t have any `IDisposable` fields: your descendants might.

This is one of the big architectural problems of `IDisposable` highlighted in [IDisposable: What your mother never told you about resource deallocation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About). Basically, unless your class is sealed you need to decide whether your descendants are likely to have `IDisposable` members. And this isn't something you can realistically predict.

So, if your descendants are likely to have `IDisposable` members, that might be a good reason to implement `IDisposable` in the base class.

Comment: The fact that your descendents might implement `IDisposable` will only be relevant if there is a realistic possibility that the last entity which holds an instance of one of your descendant types will be regarding it as an instance of your type (or some intermediate type which would not implement `IDisposable` if you don't).  There are definitely cases where this is true (e.g. with `io.stream`) but it's not really the norm.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer would be no. However, you can smartly use the nature of the `Dispose()` executement at the end of the object lifecycle. One have already gave a nice MVC example (`Html.BeginForm`)

I would like to point out one important aspect of `IDisposable` and `using() {}` statement. At the end of the `Using` statement `Dispose()` method is automatically called on the using context object (it must have implemented `IDisposable` interface, of course).

Answer (score 0):

There one more reason that no one mentioned (though it's debateful if it really worth it):
The convension says that if someone uses a class that implement `IDisposable`, it *must* call its Dispose method (either explicitly or via the 'using' statement). 
But what happens if V1 of a class (in your public API) didn't need IDisposable, but V2 does? Technically it doesn't break backward compatibility to add an interface to a class, but because of that *convension*, it is! Because old clients of your code won't call its Dispose method and may cause resources to not get freed.
The (almost) only way to avoid it is to implement IDisposable in any case you suspect that you'll need it in the future, to make sure that your clients always call your Dispose method, that some day may be really needed.
The other (and probably better) way is to implemet the lambda pattern mentioned by JaredPar above in the V2 of the API.