# If I have a Dispose method, must I implement IDisposable?

Tags: c#

I have a class that contains a `Dispose` method. In this method I abort a thread. Is it necessary to implement the `IDisposable` interface?

Comment: only if you need it...

Comment: (And if not desiring an IDisposable object, please don't call it Dispose. It's confusing. Since C# is [*nominally typed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), you'll need to implement IDisposable if you wish the object to conform to IDisposable; methods don't give objects types.)

Comment: General design qualm: Are your sure that aborting the thread is the right thing to do? (Almost always, it is not the right thing to do.) Can you use co-operative thread shutdown instead?

Comment: As @user2864740 mentioned, avoid using this name for that method if you don't plan to implement IDisposable. To learn what is the best practice you should follow, read the book Framework Design Guidelines, or learn the analysis tools, such as Gendarme, http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme.Rules.Design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement `IDisposable` interface then your class object could be used in using block that automatically call the `Dispose` method implicitly.

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472304/is-there-any-benefit-to-implementing-idisposable-on-classes-which-do-not-have-re) from JaredPar

There are only 2 reasons for implementing IDisposable on a type

- The type contains native resources which must be freed when the type is no longer used
- The type contains fields of type IDisposable

[Is there any benefit to implementing IDisposable on classes which do not have resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472304/is-there-any-benefit-to-implementing-idisposable-on-classes-which-do-not-have-re)